# XLConnect reads some, but not all empty cells as NA

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I have encountered the strangest problem with using XLConnect package for R, and I am wondering if anyone has any idea about what might be causing it.

I have written an R script to combine the data from some 100 Excel files; I load the contents of each file with the following bit:

```
tempo <- as.data.frame(readWorksheetFromFile(file = o,
                                               sheet = 1,
                                               header = FALSE,
                                               startRow = 1,
                                               endRow = 0,
                                               startCol = 1,
                                               endCol = 0,
                                               autofitRow = FALSE,
                                               autofitCol = FALSE))
```

The original files are forms that people filled in and contain the values that I need in various rows and columns. The result that I need is a data frame where each value from the form is a separate variable, and each of the files is one observation. I have mapped the structure of the files and written a script that gets me all the values that I want into a bunch of vectors, and then I cbind() and rbind() them as necessary to construct my data frame.

The script works well except for exactly *one empty cell in one file*, which XLConnect refuses to read as NA, causing the columns to mismatch.

I find where in the file "tempo" this particular form section "a.3." begins:

```
anchor.a.3. <- which(apply(tempo, c(1,2), function(x) any(grepl("^a.3.$", x))), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

(I do string matching because these forms are similarly structured, but not all form sections start in the same cell across all files).
I get the row and column indices of this cell:

```
r <- anchor.a.3.[[1]]
c <- anchor.a.3.[[2]]
```

... and then I tell R to create a vector of four values from the section "a.3.", finding them in cells with indices relative to [r, c] (the  values I need are always equally positioned with respect to this "anchor" cell:

```
 a.3. <- c(unlist(c(tempo[r+3, (c+3):(c+4)])), tempo[r+3, c+6], tempo[r+4, c+3])
```

The problem is that for one file, where the cell [r+3, c+6] has been left empty (it happens to be a merged cell G111-H111), XLConnect doesn't seem to read it as NA. The four values ought to be: "0", NA, NA, NA; whereas R gives me:

```
Col4 Col5      
 "0" NA   NA
```

Likewise, when I just ask for tempo[r+3, c+6], I get NULL as the result, not NA as I expect.

I thought the problem may be that it is a merged cell, but I get values from all the other merged cells correctly.

In fact, there are at least three other files where this same (equally merged) cell has also been left empty, and I correctly get NAs for those in the vector a.3. I tried to compare the structure of the problematic file against those files, as well as the formatting of the cell, and I cannot identify any differences.

In the problematic file, the last cell of the section a.3. that I need, tempo[r+4, c+3) is also a merged cell that has been left empty; I correctly get NA for that one too.

I did a little experiment: I typed "a" in the empty cell in the problematic file, saved it, and re-ran my script. I correctly got "0", NA, "a", NA.

I would love to reproduce the problem for you all, but I just can't: all other empty cells are read as NA. So I just can't get the NA value from that one cell in that one file! Does anyone have any idea about what might be causing this failure and what the solution is? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Open Excel and compare the number formats between the cells that are behaving differently. For example, perhaps one is "Text" and the other is "Number" or "General"? Also try to compare the cell's values directly within Excel; eg, if two empty cells behaving differently are A1 and B1 then in any other cell enter `=A1=B1`. If the result is `FALSE` then the two cells are not the same; perhaps one is empty and one has a 'space' in it?  Also, where/how were these files generated in the first place? (Are they valid `.XLSX`?) If they weren't created by Excel then the issue is likely on that end.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @ashleedawg, but no source of the problem yet! Format is "General" for both the empty cell that is read and that is not read, and `=A1=B1` evaluates as `TRUE`. There is nothing in the cell; I've actually typed something in and erased it to make sure there's nothing there, and it still doesn't work. I guess this is not a huge problem for me right now; I'm just clueless about what the cause might be.